# Counting the number of transactions by left joining a category table

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

would like get your advice on how to achieve the following. I have two tables. One is called the Category and other the Trxn. I trying to find how many transactions are are in each category. I understand I need to left join my Trxn table with Category table. But the issue is that, CategoryId in the Category table is 6 characters and this same ID is split into two columns in the Trxn table as 4 and 2 character column respectively.

How can I can join the both the columns and left join the Category table. ?? Is it possible. My aspx application has to show how many traxns have been done in each category.
I have attached a sample database schema via SQLFiddle link below.

```
SELECT Category.ID, count(Trxn.Cat_ID) FROM Category
LEFT JOIN Trxn
on Category.ID = (Trxn.Cat_ID+Trxn.STV)
where Category.Status='A'
AND Trxn.Status='ok'
group by Category.ID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6feef/2/0

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have part of your left outer join table in the where clause. You can't do that, it makes it become a normal join.

This works:

```
SELECT
  Category.ID,
  COUNT(Trxn.Cat_ID)
FROM
  Category
LEFT JOIN
  Trxn
  ON Category.ID = (rtrim(Trxn.Cat_ID)+ltrim(Trxn.STV))
  AND Trxn.Status='ok'
WHERE Category.Status='A'
GROUP BY Category.ID
```

Comment: this works, Thanks, I would like to know is it possible to show the Category Ids from the traxn table even though the Category Ids are not in the Category table. Is possible.?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way, but if there are category ids not in the category table, then I would suggest adding them to the category table and creating a foreign key on the trxn.cat_id to category.id. It sounds like a design issue.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason there was a space after cat_id when you concatenate the values. I was able to find this by just running. I just noticed the data type is a char.

```
select cat_id + stv from trxn
```

I trimmed of the space and the query is working.

```
SELECT Category.ID, count(Trxn.Cat_ID) FROM Category
LEFT JOIN Trxn
on Category.ID = (rtrim(Trxn.Cat_ID)+ltrim(Trxn.STV)) AND Trxn.Status='ok'
where Category.Status='A'
group by Category.ID
```

Comment: But you now displaying the rest of the categories in the Category table. Left Join should show 0 right where there is no corresponding record

Comment: I edited the query and moved `trxn.status='ok'` into the join. If this still isn't what you are looking for. Please post your expected result set.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem in your join is there's a space when you use Trxn.Cat_ID+Trxn.STV that's why it cant connect to your Category table because there is no value like that, here is my solution to your problem i already test it on my own.. and also if you are JOINING tables better if you exercise your self to use an Alias :)

```
SELECT A.ID,count(A.ID) FROM Category A
LEFT JOIN Trxn B ON REPLACE(B.Cat_ID+B.STV,' ','') = A.ID
WHERE A.Status = 'A'
AND B.Status = 'ok'
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

When running the following query,

```
SELECT Trxn.Cat_ID,Trxn.STV, Trxn.Cat_ID+Trxn.STV
FROM TRXN;
```

You get an output as

```
CAT_ID |    STV | COLUMN_2
EBL01  |    06  | EBL01 06
EBL01  |    06  | EBL01 06
EBL02  |    06  | EBL02 06
EBL03  |    06  | EBL03 06
```

You will be able to notice the space in COLUMN_2 which has to be removed for comparison. Hence, try replacing all the spaces in your query and it should work. May be you can try:

```
SELECT Category.ID, count(Trxn.Cat_ID) TRANSACTION_COUNT FROM Category
LEFT JOIN Trxn
on Category.ID = REPLACE(Trxn.Cat_ID+Trxn.STV,' ','')
where Category.Status='A'
AND Trxn.Status='ok'
group by Category.ID;
```

The query gives the following output in fiddle:

```
ID         | TRANSACTION_COUNT
EBL0106    |    2
```