# Counting the number of transaction hourly for the past 8 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is the extension of  and earlier question I asked. Based on new the requirements from my clients, I need to retrieve number of transactions on a hourly scale for the past 8 hours.

For example: I login at 5:30 am on 27 June 2014, I should be able to see the number of transactions that has happened 8 hours prior to my login but in an hourly grouping.

Something like this.

```
27/06/2014 04-05 Hours 2 Transactions
27/06/2014 03-04 Hours 1 Transactions
27/06/2014 02-03 Hours 3 Transactions
27/06/2014 01-02 Hours 4 Transactions
27/06/2014 00-01 Hours 0 Transactions
26/06/2014 23-00 Hours 0 Transactions
26/06/2014 22-23 Hours 1 Transactions
26/06/2014 21-22 Hours 1 Transactions
26/06/2014 20-21 Hours 3 Transactions
```

The current SQL script I have works on a daily based such as

```
 27/06/2014 04-05 Hours 2 Transactions
 27/06/2014 03-04 Hours 1 Transactions
 27/06/2014 02-03 Hours 3 Transactions
 27/06/2014 01-02 Hours 4 Transactions
 27/06/2014 00-01 Hours 0 Transactions
```

but this is not I want, can anyone advise on how to modify my script. Please

```
 SELECT 
     DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, DateTimeStart), 0) AS ForDate,
     DATEPART(hour, DateTimeStart) AS OnHour, 
     TTID.TTID, COUNT(Trxn.TTID) AS 'TrxnCount'
 FROM 
     TTID 
 LEFT JOIN 
     Trxn ON TTID.TTID = (rtrim(Trxn.TTID) + ltrim(Trxn.STV)) 
          AND Trxn.Status = 'ok' 
 WHERE 
     TTID.Status = 'A' 
     AND DateTimeStart = '2014-06-27' 
 GROUP BY 
     DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, DateTimeStart), 0),
     DATEPART(hour, DateTimeStart), TTID.TTID
 ORDER BY 
     DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, DateTimeStart), 0) DESC
```

Comment: This question is actually combining both http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399456/counting-the-number-of-transactions-by-left-joining-a-category-table  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001718/sql-server-group-by-count-of-datetime-per-hour

Comment: Sample Schema is available at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bca10

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @LastHour AS datetime;
SET @LastHour = DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, GETDATE()), 0);

WITH HourOffsets AS (
            SELECT -1 AS Offset
  UNION ALL SELECT -2
  UNION ALL SELECT -3
  UNION ALL SELECT -4
  UNION ALL SELECT -5
  UNION ALL SELECT -6
  UNION ALL SELECT -7
  UNION ALL SELECT -8
)
,Periods AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(hour, Offset, @LastHour) AS PeriodStartTime
          ,DATEADD(hour, Offset + 1, @LastHour) AS PeriodEndTime
    FROM HourOffsets
)
,Transactions AS (
    SELECT Periods.PeriodStartTime
          ,COUNT(*) AS TransactionCount
    FROM Periods
         LEFT JOIN TTID
             ON TTID.DateTimeStart >= Periods.PeriodStartTime
                AND TTID.DateTimeStart < Periods.PeriodEndTime
         LEFT JOIN Trxn
             ON TTID.TTID = (rtrim(Trxn.TTID)+ltrim(Trxn.STV))
             AND Trxn.Status='ok'
    WHERE TTID.Status IS NULL
          OR TTID.Status = 'A'
    GROUP BY Periods.PeriodStartTime
)
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), PeriodStartTime, 103)
      ,CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(hour, Periods.PeriodStartTime)) + '-'
       CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(hour, Periods.PeriodEndTime))
      ,TransactionCount
FROM Transactions
```